# Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25

Tags: smtp, localhost, php, mail-server

I have a little problem.

When I click send on my contact form I get the following warning:

```
Warning: mail() [function.mail]:
Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25,
verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()
```

I use 64bit Win7, but I have no idea what should I set up to make this work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your php.ini file you can configure which mailserver to use:

```
[mail function]
SMTP = mymailserver.example.com
```

Alternatively you can install a local mailserver as described here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mail.php#77499